# Git clone on already existing Magento installation

Tags: magento-2.1, git

I am developing an e-shop with **Magento 2.1.x**. I am using `git` as version control and the `.gitignore` file shipped with the installation of Magento 2.
Now, a colleague of mine, will join the project to help developing some parts of it.

I thought that the best practice would be to install a local copy of Magento on its computer and then make a `git clone` to download the custom parts. Is that the correct flow? I do like this I get a lot of untracked files..

Answer (score 1):

since Magento uses composer you git clone the project to you local folder and the run from the command line in the root folder

```
composer install
```

After the remaining files are installed you run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two different methods.

**1. Clone from your existing repository:**

Before cloning you have to check what are files are not included in `.gitignore` file. If you want to clone the `<magento_root_dir>/vendor` files you can remove from `.gitignore` and automatically it will be cloned to the local directory. Otherwise, if you want to exclude the `<magento_root_dir>/vendor` files, add to `.gitignore` and obviously you should run the `composer install` command after doing this. After that, you can able to push the changes to the cloud every time when you need it.

**2. Fork into the new repository:**

You can create a new repository and fork from the existing repository. Then clone the files from the newly forked repository as mentioned above. Your colleague can able to push the change to the new repository and from there he/she needs to send the merge request and finally you can merge the files. So without your knowledge, nobody can able to push the files directly.